# Is Promise.all are really fast?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api

for one request from my api, I have to download data from another/external API x4 times, earlier it took about 3 seconds to complete the request, while after using `Promise.all ()` with calling the functions to retrieve data from an external API, this time decreased to about 0.4-0.6s, example code below:

```
const [ responseOne, responseTwo, responseThree, responseFour ] = await Promise.all([
    this.fetchDataOne(),
    this.fetchDataTwo(),
    this.fetchDataThree(),
    this.fetchDataFour()
])
```

simpley function to fetch data from external api:

```
    async fetchDataOne(): Promise<IModel> {
        const response: IModel =  await fetch(`someUrl`);
        return await this.parseDataToObject(response);
    }
```

`parseDataToObject()` function is a simply casting

```
                let parsedData: IModel= <IModel>response;
                return parsedData;
```

Is there any way here to increase performance so that the execution time of my request, which consists of several more external APIs, is reduced?

thanks for any solution, i want my request to be executed below 0.1 of second

Comment: May you share what was done before using `Promise.all`?

Comment: you say `about 0.4-0.6` and `i want my request to be executed below 1 second`, isn't it already fulfilled?

Comment: @appleapple i correct :)

Comment: ok so you want if be faster.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Hi, nothing is doing before Promise.all in function when i launch this promise

Comment: but have you check whether individual request can be done under 0.1s?

Comment: 0.4 - 0.6 is quite good for 4 requests. You could add a loading animation to your UI to make it feel snappier.

Comment: Not happy with this words, but `Promise.All` does not affect performance of the each function. It just gives you nice way to handle parallel request and nothing more

Comment: @appleapple exactly

Comment: @Drag13 hmmm ok, but with using Promise.all and paraller request my execution time is much faster than launch every function one after one

Comment: You can remove the `await` from `return await this.parseDataToObject(response);`, as it doesn't return a promise (not that it affects performance in a significant way, just a side-note)

Comment: @svelteDev Request with Promise.All will be faster cause all requests are in parallel. If you are doing sequential requests (one by one) it will be longer. But execution time of each function will be more less the same (depends on API timings)

Comment: You cannot simply make it below 0.1 seconds if the response time of any of 1 request running in parallel has a response time greater than 0.1 sec

Comment: You could start removing the unnecessary extra tick you have per each async function so that instead of `return await this.parseDataToObject(response);` you just return `return this.parseDataToObject(response);` ... async functions are *always* a promise, there's rarely a need to await whatever these return. P.S. this won't give you seconds, but it'll give you right code ;-)

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi i can't because my `parseDataToObject()` is an `async` function :(

Comment: that's exactly why you *can* ... you can read more here: https://webreflection.medium.com/a-better-async-await-approach-2d130de5f39a but just drop await before the return as it's completely useless in your case.

Comment: "*Is there any way here to increase performance so that the execution time of my request is reduced?*" - No. You already run the four requests in parallel, and the slowest of them takes 0.4-0.6s. There's nothing you can do about that in your code. Make the API server faster and/or get a faster internet connection. Or deal with the fact that getting the results in the UI is not immediate.